# How do I mount a Docker volume while using a Windows host?

Tags: windows, docker, containers, volume, boot2docker

Mounting a Docker volume while being under a Windows host, has been a huge pain for me, and I could not get it to work.

Currently I got the following simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5-apache
RUN apt-get update
```

When I build an image from it, and start a container

```
docker build -t phisch:dev .
docker run phisch:dev
```

the container starts properly.

But when I am trying to mount a volume,

```
docker run -v /c/Users/phisch/dev/htdocs:/var/www phisch:dev
```

the following message will be displayed:

```
C:\Users\phisch\dev>docker run -v /c/Users/phisch/dev/htdocs:/var/www phisch:dev
no such file or directory
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command not found or does not exist..
```

The `/var/www` directory definitely exists in the container, and trying other directories does not change the result. Prepending a trailing slash to the host-side directory does not help either. (`//c/Users/phisch/dev/htdocs`)

How do I mount for example `/var/www` to `C:/Users/phisch/dev/htdocs`?

```
phisch@DESKTOP-UC1LB9J MINGW64 ~/dev (master)
$ docker inspect phisch:dev
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:73c1533222a905a378f12505ccbd9e9b34cde5a4b34ed008c39e23d5d58a9c91",
        "RepoTags": [
            "dev_web:latest",
            "phisch:dev",
            "phisch:dev3"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [],
        "Parent": "sha256:d2c4149d86c4dfceaff0e9c4eb5a5d42ca7815f81dd08baad4dc8bda6db2fb10",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2016-02-10T12:16:37.667236134Z",
        "Container": "dad811f51ef3b94d9845d13a0e43ad07ccd5684ea2747b3846accdc71abeb628",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "e06f5a03fe1f",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
                "PHP_EXTRA_BUILD_DEPS=apache2-dev",
                "PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS=--with-apxs2",
                "GPG_KEYS=0BD78B5F97500D450838F95DFE857D9A90D90EC1 6E4F6AB321FDC07F2C332E3AC2BF0BC433CFC8B3",
                "PHP_VERSION=5.6.18",
                "PHP_FILENAME=php-5.6.18.tar.xz",
                "PHP_SHA256=54dd9106c3469bc7028644d72ac140af00655420bbaaf4a742a64e9ed02ec1b0"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "apt-get update"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:d2c4149d86c4dfceaff0e9c4eb5a5d42ca7815f81dd08baad4dc8bda6db2fb10",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/var/www/html",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": [],
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "DockerVersion": "1.10.0",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "e06f5a03fe1f",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
                "PHP_EXTRA_BUILD_DEPS=apache2-dev",
                "PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS=--with-apxs2",
                "GPG_KEYS=0BD78B5F97500D450838F95DFE857D9A90D90EC1 6E4F6AB321FDC07F2C332E3AC2BF0BC433CFC8B3",
                "PHP_VERSION=5.6.18",
                "PHP_FILENAME=php-5.6.18.tar.xz",
                "PHP_SHA256=54dd9106c3469bc7028644d72ac140af00655420bbaaf4a742a64e9ed02ec1b0"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "apache2-foreground"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:d2c4149d86c4dfceaff0e9c4eb5a5d42ca7815f81dd08baad4dc8bda6db2fb10",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/var/www/html",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": [],
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 491287784,
        "VirtualSize": 491287784,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "aufs",
            "Data": null
        }
    }
]
```

**It turns out the container-side directory `/var/www` needs to be empty, since it had a sub-directory `www`. Docker was not able to use it as a mounting point.**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is possible the `/` is interpreted as an option by the CMD Windows shell.

Try first a docker-machine ssh default, in order to open an ssh session in your VM. From *there*, try the docker run again: `docker run -v /c/Users/phisch/dev/htdocs:/var/www phisch:dev`

As commented by [thaJeztah](https://github.com/thaJeztah) in [issue 18290](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18290#issuecomment-160323229):

> You could consider using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/); docker-compose allows you to define bind-mounted volumes relative to the location of the `docker-compose.yml` file.
> Using a `docker-compose` file allows you to specify all options needed to run your containers in a single file, which makes it ideal for sharing between team members (ie, just run `docker-compose up -d` will start all containers for the project with the right options).

[This comment](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18290#issuecomment-175191098) mentions adding a second /:

```
docker run -v //c/Users/phisch/dev/htdocs:`/var/www` phisch:dev
```

Even in the docker toolbox msys shell session, there are issues (like [issue 282](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/282))

[Pyetro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3229228/pyetro) notes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315996/how-do-i-mount-a-docker-volume-while-using-a-windows-host/35316813?noredirect=1#comment127451796_35316813):

> In Windows, a double slash is needed at the beginning of the path to indicate the working directory.
> Just to work with short path use like this:
>
> ```
> docker run -v //$(PWD)/folder:/folder ...
> ```

---

After lengthy discussion, the issue was that `/var/www` had a folder in it.

Mounting  `/c/Users/phisch/dev/htdoc` onto an empty folder does work, but might not give the expected result, as the default CMD `apache2-foreground` might still serve its content based on `/var/www` (which would not have `htdocs` content if that `htdocs` is mounted onto another folder).

Comment: Running `docker run -v /c/Users/phisch/dev/htdocs:/var/www phisch:dev` from within the docker machine (ssh session), i receive the same error message like before.

Comment: @PhilippSchaffrath there seem to be *two* errors: the `Container command not found or does not exist` involve the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`. If that command refers to a file which is supposed to be mounted, then we need to resolve the first. Does `c:\Users\phisch\dev\htdocs` exists? With that exact case?

Comment: Yes this directory exists with the exact case. Those 2 messages always come together. Either everything works (when using no volume), or both messages are printed.

Comment: @PhilippSchaffrath What is your ENTRYPOINT and CMD?

Comment: Using docker-compose to mount volumes results in the exact same messages.

Comment: @PhilippSchaffrath in an ssh session, can you cd to `/c/Users/phisch/dev/htdocs`?

Comment: I have not set an ENTRYPOINT, and what do you mean by CMD?

Comment: @PhilippSchaffrath `CMD` would be the default parameter passed to the `ENTRYPOINT` (which, by default, is `sh -c`): https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: Allright, neither CMD nor ENTRYPOINT are defined in my Dockerfile.

Comment: @PhilippSchaffrath so... what your container is supposed to do when you do a `docker run phisch:dev`? Would (still in an ssh session) a `docker run -v //c/Users/phisch/dev/htdocs:/var/www phisch:dev ls` (note the final ls) work better?

Comment: The image is supposed to provide apache and php for a local development environment. Running `docker run -v //c/Users/phisch/dev/htdocs:/var/www phisch:dev ls` through ssh prints the same error.

Comment: @PhilippSchaffrath OK, can you do a `docker inspect phisch:dev` and tell me what the `ENTRYPOINT` and  `CMD` are?

Comment: Inspect gives me `"Cmd": ["/bin/sh", "-c", "apt-get update"]` and  `"Entrypoint": null` for `ContainerConfig` and `"Cmd": ["apache2-foreground"]` and `"Entrypoint": null` for `Config`.

Comment: @PhilippSchaffrath You can ignore `ContainerConfig` when inspecting an image. Is `apache2-foreground` visible in your container? Is it in your `$PATH` in a container bash session?

Comment: It should be, but i am not sure how to validate it. I have included the `inspect` output in my original question.

Comment: @PhilippSchaffrath do a `docker run -v /c/Users/phisch/dev/htdocs:/var/www phisch:dev bash` (no '`//`'): that should open a bash session in which you can do an `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Running with the volume it gives me the same error like before. Without volume it does not start a bash session. `C:\Users\phisch>docker run phisch:dev bash

C:\Users\phisch>`

Comment: Try it in an ssh session

Comment: I had to pass the parameters -t and -i to allocate a pseudo-tty and keep stdin. PATH contains `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`.

Comment: Well, can search for the apache2-foreground script? Is it in one of those paths?

Comment: It is in `/usr/local/bin` and contains those lines: `set -e`, `rm -f /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid`, `exec apache2 -DFOREGROUND`.

Comment: @PhilippSchaffrath that should work. Do you confirm you canot open a bash wile (from an ssh session) you are trying to mount an host folder? `docker run -it --rm -v /c/Users/phisch/dev/htdocs:/var/www phisch:dev bash`

Comment: Yes, it fails with the same message.

Comment: @PhilippSchaffrath When you do a `docker run -it --rm hisch:dev bash`, are able to do an `ls /c/Users/phisch/dev/htdocs` and `ls /var/www` ?

Comment: `/var/www` of course is available. Oddly `/c` is not available. It is available on the linux vm that boot2docker creates, but not inside the docker container running on it.

Comment: But this makes sense, since `/c/Users/phisch/dev/htdocs` needs to be on the host and in the boot2docker vm (which runs docker). And docker should mount it from the linux-host (boot2docker) to the docker container.

Comment: @PhilippSchaffrath That is expected: inside the container, only /var/www is available, with the *content* of /c/... mounted in it.

Comment: @PhilippSchaffrath So from docker, an `ls /c/Users/phisch/dev/htdocs` does work, does it not?

Comment: From the boot2docker VM `ls /c/Users/phisch/dev/htdocs` works.

Comment: When you do *not* mount that path, is there files in `/var/www`? (when doing a `docker run -it --rm hisch:dev bash`)

Comment: Yes, there is one sub-directory in it. Might that be the problem?

Comment: Actually this was the problem. When i mount an empty directory, it works just fine.

Comment: @PhilippSchaffrath OK. I have included that conclusion in the answer for more visibility, but I have added a caveat.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i appreciate it! I included the answer into my original post aswell.

Comment: In windows, a double slash is needed at the beginning of the path to indicate the working directory. Just to work with short path use like this ``docker run -v //$(PWD)/folder:/folder ...``

Comment: @Pyetro Good point, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 20):

I use Docker for Windows with PowerShell and use `$PWD` to refer to the current directory when mounting a volume, and it works well for me. A couple of examples:

```
docker run -p 2368:2368 -v $PWD/ghost:/var/lib/ghost -d ghost

docker run -p 2368:2368 -v $PWD/:/var/lib/ghost -d ghost
```

Comment: Instead of `$PWD` you can also just use `"C:\path\to\my\host\folder"` or `"//c/path/to/my/host/folder"` so this can work in other cli's than PowerShell as well :)

Comment: @ArnovanOordt if you like absolute paths 

Comment: @JohnnyOshika best answer , these days all use powershell with vs code

Answer (score 7):

If we are talking about Docker on Windows then we have to take in account the fact that all containers are run on VirtualBox.

Before mounting volume to a container we have to be sure that particular folder is available for VirtualBox.

Firstly, to define the name of the current running Docker machine, run

```
$ docker-machine.exe  active
default
```

Secondly, add shared folder to VirtualBox:

```
$ VBoxManage sharedfolder add default --name "some_project" --hostpath D:\Projects\some_project
```

Thirdly, create the folder

```
$ docker-machine.exe ssh default 'sudo mkdir --parents /d/projects/some_project'
```

Fourthly, mount it:

```
$ docker-machine.exe ssh default 'sudo mount -t vboxsf some_project /d/projects/some_project'
```

Finally, create a container:

```
$ docker run -v //d/projects/some_project://d/projects/some_project -d some-image_name
```

Answer (score 6):

The old `-v` syntax still works but now [the recommended way](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) is to use `--mount` e.g.

```
docker run --rm -dp 8080:8080 --mount type=bind,src=C:\web\dev,target=C:\web\dev my-docker
```

Comment: This saved me lots of work..Thanks

Answer (score 5):

First, make sure you run from **powershell** as a administrator.

next, run a command like:

```
docker run --name=ken -p 8080:80 -v //c/users/Ken/Desktop/docker:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d nginx
```

tested working on Windows 11.

Comment: Thanks, just a note, I wasn't required to run it as **administrator**.