# Intellij docker integration plugin and invalid volume specification on docker-machine for windows 10

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, windows-10, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm trying to use intellij's docker integration plugin with the following tutorial on [Get started with Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) running on a docker-machine installed on windows 10. My project is located here: `C:\Users\bob\IdeaProjects\foo`.

If I run `docker-compose up` from the command line on my windows host, everything works. If I try to create a Docker deployment using the intellij docker integration plugin and specify the docker-compose.yml, I get the following error.

```
ERROR: for web  Cannot create container for service web: invalid bind mount spec "C:\\Users\\bob\\IdeaProjects\\foo:/code:rw": invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\bob\IdeaProjects\foo:/code:rw'
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
No containers created for service: web
Failed to deploy 'Compose:  docker-compose.yml': Some services/containers not started
```

I think this is only an issue with the intellij docker integration plugin. I tried creating a .env with COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS set to either 1 or 0 with no success.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix the intellij docker integration plugin to mount volumes such as `.:/code`?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/35316813/104891 help?

Comment: Even after reading that, it still doesn't help. Like I mentioned `docker-compose up` works when using the windows command prompt, but not from the docker integration plugin. I can't seem to figure out the difference.

Comment: FYI, I configure my windows command prompt the usual way using:

`docker-machine env`,
`@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env') DO @%i`,
`cd c:\Users\bob\IdeaProjects\foo`,
`docker-compose up`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extract from Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/):

> Compose supports declaring default environment variables in an environment file named .env placed in the folder docker-compose command is executed from (**current working directory**).

The tricky part here is to identify the "current working directory", which is used by Intellij IDEA. Unfortunately, Docker plugin does not allow to specify it explicitly. So, I did some research and finally found the answer in IDEA [javadoc](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/execution/configurations/GeneralCommandLine.java#L52):

> By default, a current directory of the IDE process is used (usually a "bin/" directory of IDE installation).

After putting the .env file under /bin of my IDEA installation and restarting the IDE, the issue was resolved for me.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: There's a bug in the intellij docker plugin. I provided a link mentioning that the fix will be coming in intellij version 2017.1.