# Implement Edge containers from Google Cloud vision to a windows machine

Tags: docker, computer-vision, google-cloud-automl

I'm trying to implement Edge containers from Google Cloud vision to My windows machine, and no I' m stuck in running a Docker in command line to serve Edge model inferences with REST APIs :

```
C:\Users\User-Name\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>docker run --rm --name 
automl_high_accuracy_model_cpu -p 8501:8501 -v gs://first-edge-253208 
vcm/models/edge/ICN1840948916028989885/2019-09-26_08-53-35-399_tf-saved- 
model:/mounted_model/0001 -t gcr.io/automl-vision-ondevice/gcloud-container-1.12.0:latest
```

> docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification:
>   'gs://first-edge-253208-vcm/models/edge/ICN1840948916028989885/2019-09-26_08-53-35-399_tf-saved-model:/mounted_model/0001'.
>   See 'docker run --help'.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is because your trying to mount a volume with GCS inside **/mounted_model/0001**, Docker can't read from a gs path.

Before proceeding you need to download the model at your local disk

```
gs cp gs://<bucket_model>/<path>/ .
```

Then run docker and use the full path model (point to the directory where your model is located)

```
docker run --rm --name 
automl_high_accuracy_model_cpu -p 8501:8501 -v <full_local_path_to_model>:/mounted_model/0001 -t gcr.io/automl-vision-ondevice/gcloud-container-1.12.0:latest
```

Also You can create a new image, using **gcr.io/automl-vision-ondevice/gcloud-container-1.12.0:latest** as the base, this could help you to mount it easily inside a VM or Kubernetes.

Create a **Dockerfile** at the same level where you have your file model (.pb) is located

```
FROM gcr.io/automl-vision-ondevice/gcloud-container-1.12.0:latest
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/mounted_model/0001/
COPY . /tmp/mounted_model/0001/
```

And then, build the image

```
sudo docker build . -t <image_name>
```

After running your container, you should see this in the logs

```
I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:339] Exporting HTTP/REST API at:localhost:8501 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, Im using Windows 10, not Linux, I still having the same error :

docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\User-Name\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK:\Users\User-Name\AppDat \Local\Google\Cloud SDK\Trained_Mode \ICN1840948916028989885\2019-09-26_08-53-35-399_tf-saved-model:/mounted_model/0001'.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: Are you using this path to indicate your model location? C:\Users\User-Name\AppDat\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\Trained_Mode\ICN1840948916028989885\2019-09-26_08-53-35-399_tf-saved-model

Comment: Yes, I used this this Path : this is the command :
docker run --rm --name automl_high_accuracy_model_cpu -p 8501:8501 -v "%cd%:\Users\User-Name\AppDat \Local\Google\Cloud SDK\Trained_Mode \ICN1840948916028989885\2019-09-26_08-53-35-399_tf-saved-model":/mounted_model/0001 -t gcr.io/automl-vision-ondevice/gcloud-container-1.12.0:latest

Comment: I have found a similar issue for mounting volumes on docker with windows, this can be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315996/how-do-i-mount-a-docker-volume-while-using-a-windows-host