# Pass configuration file to mosquitto in Docker container

Tags: docker, mosquitto

Trying to run masquitto Docker container on Windows. I have directory structure:

```
..
mosquitto
  config
     -- mosquitto.conf
  data
  log
```

I run command:

```
docker run -it -p 1883:1883 -p 9001:9001 -v mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf -v /mosquitto/data -v /mosquitto/log eclipse-mosquitto
```

Got error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: source /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c54f317f73085489398e1b2c4ffbc85fbdb18073e8a0fa60f11a7f7222fbc49d/merged/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf is not directory.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

What I do wrong?

UPD

I tried to provide full path to config file on host machine:

```
docker run -it -p 1883:1883 -p 9001:9001 -v C:/docker_tst/eclipse-mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf  eclipse-mosquitto
```

Got error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:459: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:59: mounting "/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/docker_tst/eclipse-mosquitto/mosquitto.conf" to rootfs at "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d9a7cbcb0f85b195dc5ee2d0999b3df8c84324552f6c45cf218876e9b96ed826/merged/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf" caused: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.
PS C:\docker_tst\eclipse-mosquitto>
```

Comment: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34135752/4676641), if you're mounting a single file, you should try providing the absolute path. If you're using a bash/zsh shell, can you try: `-v $PWD/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf`

Comment: I do it in Windows. How to provide full path from cmd or PowerShell?

Comment: I don't know of a convenient way to do that besides converting the path somewhat manually per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35316813/4676641) because of how Docker reads paths after the `-v` flag. I ran `Get-Location` in powershell and converted the path: `C:\Users\Username\Path` to `//c/users/username/path/file.conf` for the "host" part of the mount.

Comment: I tried to provide full path to mosquitto.conf on host machine, but got error. More details in question body UPD

Comment: I'm sorry for the back and forth but are you sure that's the right path to the .conf? From your folder structure, it looked like the path to `mosquito.conf` might be in `./mosquito/config/mosquito.conf`? So something like `-v C:/docker_tst/eclipse-mosquitto/mosquito/config/mosquito.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf` instead?

Comment: You are right, thanks ! Not I have no errors :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments, the solution was to provide an absolute path to the single mounted file, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34135752/4676641).

On Unix based systems or in Windows Subsystem for Linux, you can do this by running something like:

```
docker run -v $PWD/filename:/path/in/container IMAGE_NAME
```

However, the process is different on Windows, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35316813/4676641).

In PowerShell, you can run `Get-Location` or `pwd` to get the current directory where your file is and switch the `\` to `/` (forward slashes). For this example, the solution was to use this command:

```
docker run -it -p 1883:1883 -p 9001:9001 -v C:/docker_tst/eclipse-mosquitto/mosquito/config/mosquito.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf  eclipse-mosquitto
```